# Не срабатывает npm install

Tags: npm

Добрый день. Поставил на чистую машину node.js. Создаю новый проект, копирую package.json, пытаюсь выполнить npm install, но сталкиваюсь с такой бедой:
[image: Ошибка npm]

гуглинг к сожалению не помог. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать, и как с этим бороться?

Comment: package.json - он какой? может попробовать его создать, и потом зависимости прописать?

Answer (score 2):

У меня такая же проблема была при работе с Docker, помогло добавление параметра:

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

Рекомендую также попробовать использовать Yarn (https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) вместо npm